# Dynamics CRM 4.0 - change Mail Merge to save in Office 2007 format (.docx)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

We are developing workflow to change properties in Word documents that have been saved against letter activities created by mail merge, and would prefer to code against Office 2007 for simplicity, and to save having to recode in the future.

Any ideas?

Comment: Guys Come one :)
Solve this problem, I have put my rep on the line :)

Comment: What is the actual question. Change Mail Merge to save in Office 2007?

Comment: Its not as as simple as changing the Mail Merge Template to use Word 2007.

Comment: Sadly it no that simple. I have tried that.

Comment: Provide a definition of the problem. You're request is extremly vague.

Comment: Did the mail merge work when u changed the template?

Comment: No The template does not stop the CRM word add-in saving the word file back to crm as  a doc format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After raising this with microsoft support, it's is not possible out of the box.

I will write a CRM plugin that will convert  the word doc to docx format on the anotonation enitity before saving to crm.

It's a bit of a pain. but will work.